# Differences between R2009 and R2015 Matlab

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I have the following code which works on matlab R2015 until the concatenation of `I2D` but stops at `imadjust` because I'm out of memory. I'm treating 2249 images of 1984*1984 pixels on a 16 Go RAM and 64 bit.

When I run the **same** code a more powerful computer (24 Go RAM) but with the R2009 version of Matlab, the code stops at the `cat` step saying the arguments dimensions are not consistent.

I don't get why it is working on R2015 and not on R2009. Notice that I will **have to** run the code on R2009 (but that's another story). Therefore, the problem of out of memory will maybe not be important but I don't know yat because it is not working on the R2009 version (24 Go RAM).

```
%reading data and inverting the GV
for k=1:n
    I = imread(fullfile(rep,list1(k).name),ext(3:end));
    for i=1:Row
        for j=1:Col
            I(i,j)=255-I(i,j);
        end
     end 
    nomFichier=sprintf('Xa1_3D_%04d.bmp',k);
    imwrite(I,fullfile(rep2,nomFichier),ext(3:end));
end

%Now, we want to read all the images at once to have all the available
%informations for the histogram adjustement
chemin = fullfile(rep2,ext);
list2 = dir(chemin);
o=numel(list2);
I2{o}=ones;
for k=1:o
    I2{k} = imread(fullfile(rep2,list2(k).name),ext(3:end));
end

%Combination of images in 2D matrix and hist adjustement
I2D=cat(2,I2{:});
I2D=imadjust(I2D);
```

Comment: Not what you asked. But for a speedup you could replace the for loops with `I(1:Row,1:Col) = 255-(1:Row,1:Col)`. If `Row` and `Col`is the heigth and width of the image you can only use `I = 255-I`.

Comment: Is it possible that on the one machine there is an additional image file with a different size. I suggest you could test all your contents of I2 for equal size before using cat operator. Check also number of channels.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake, I didn't check it well throught. Firstly, there was an image with a different size and after I deleted, it was still present in the temp folder... Sorry ! But thanks for the speedup tips. It works well on the 24Go RAM.